# Signals on Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, unix

I am writing code in C++ using Win32 API wherever needed. I wish to accomplish the following. When a certain event occurs I want to set an `alarm()` or start a timer which will send a `SIGALRM` signal to the process after 1s. The process should continue once the alarm has been set. It might so happen that I may have to cancel the alarm (or stop the timer) if certain conditions are met. What system calls can help me do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudocode:

```
// to create a waitable, signallable object
HANDLE myHandle = CreateEvent 

// to wait for 1000ms 
WaitForSingleObject(1000L)    

// to interrupt the wait - check return code on WaitForSingleObject for timeout vs signal
SetEvent(myHandle)
```

[Docs for CreateEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682396%28VS.85%29.aspx) should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

`timeSetEvent` and `timeKillEvent` allow the same functionality on windows